# Does a particular statement in Lambda calculus count as a proof?

Tags: computer-science, formal-proofs

*Context: I'm writing a [blog post](https://leontrolski.github.io/lambda-calculus.html) on Lambda calculus for working programmers (like me) that want an insight into some of the truths from planet formal-proofs, but are reluctant to deep dive into all the weird syntax :-)*

I have a formal system set up (below) where I'd like to prove(?) `1 + 2 = 3`.

Given that, would the following statement be **true**?

> - I have a formal system of symbols that all make up single argument functions.
> - The value of a *function that has been called* is the value obtained by repeatedly applying β-reduction.
> - We arbitrarily draw a correspondence between certain functions and integers (Church numerals).
> - We arbitrarily decide what it means to increment an integer, and based on that, what it means to do addition on two integers.
> - We write out 1 + 2 in the formal system, and it β-reduces to our representation of 3.
> - Therefore we have **proven** 1 + 2 = 3 (within our system).

I'm slightly reluctant to say it, because things like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence#Natural_deduction_and_lambda_calculus) hint I need to be e.g. using simply typed lambda calculus.

1. Do I need to introduce the idea of booleans (see my blog post), and then a proof is something that evaluates to `true`?
2. Is there any connection to proofs at all with what I've laid out?
3. Is it simply too fuzzy to be saying things like "we **proved** 1 + 2 = 3?
4. Is it correct that choosing to represent integers as Church numerals and choosing how to define addition are arbitrary (although obviously handy)? *If you say "given this arbitrary way we defined addition, 1 + 2 = 3", is that even saying much of substance?*
5. If it is a proof, which bits below correspond to which formal-proof-y words?

````
// Proving(?) 1 + 2 = 3
// Lambda calculus syntax:     λx.f x
// Corresponds to JavaScript:  x => f(x)

// Church numerals
_0 = f => a => a
_1 = f => a => f(a)
_2 = f => a => f(f(a))
_3 = f => a => f(f(f(a)))
// ...

// Define what it means to increment a integer
// and to add two integers together
inc  = n => f => a => f(n(f)(a))
plus = n => m => n(inc)(m) 

// Substitute and β-reduce
plus(_1)(_2)                                                   // substitute plus, _1, _2
(n => m => n(inc)(m))(f => a => f(a))(f => a => f(f(a)))       // β n
(m => (f => a => f(a))(inc)(m))(f => a => f(f(a)))             // β m
(f => a => f(a))(inc)(f => a => f(f(a)))                       // substitute inc
(f => a => f(a))(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(f => a => f(f(a))) // β first f
(a => (n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(a))(f => a => f(f(a)))       // β first a
(n => f => a => f(n(f)(a)))(f => a => f(f(a)))                 // β n
f => a => f((f => a => f(f(a)))(f)(a))                         // β second f
f => a => f((a => f(f(a)))(a))                                 // β second a
f => a => f(f(f(a)))
// This final form is the Church numeral 3
// ∴ 1 + 2 = 3
```
````

Comment: "$1+1=3$" is also a statement in this system, but it cannot be proven. That the statement is true is crucial. I do not know whether Lambda Calculus is complete , in this case this would also be sufficient. The statement itself is however usually not a proof. If so, proofs would be trivial, we just would have to claim the (true) statement to prove it.